# How to import images to android application?

Tags: android, image, file-handling, photos

I want to import images to my android application to apply different operations over them. It's just like [Vault](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netqin.ps&hl=en) App which is on the store. I want to click a button and import images from my cell phone gallery folder to my application photo's folder.

Comment: You mean to get Image from internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to click a button and import images from my cell phone gallery folder to my application photo's folder.

1) Create your folder in `/Android/data/`

2) On click of the button get the file path then move that file to your app folder without any extension. So any other program not able to fine it in **gallery**, **music player**

3) for more security  you can also apply encryption on it before moving it to your folder

Answer (score 0):

Your question's answer is here. 
https://github.com/Cutta/MultipleImagePicker